# retrieve data with where condition laravel 5.2 into controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

the question is how to get data from foreign key into my controller and pass to Session flash message view.

> AbsenController@store

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'siswa_id' => 'required',
            'keterangan' => 'required',
        ]);

    $alpaCount = Absen::where('siswa_id', '=', $request->siswa_id)
                        ->where('keterangan', '=', 'Alpa')
                        ->count();

    if (Absen::where('siswa_id', '=', $request->siswa_id)
        ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()')
        ->exists()) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Data Telah Tersedia');
    } elseif($alpaCount >= 3) {
        $absen = new Absen;
        $absen->siswa_id = $request->siswa_id;
        $absen->keterangan = $request->keterangan;
        $absen->save();

        $nama = Siswa::where('id', '=', $request->siswa_id)->get();


        Session::flash('warning', $nama->nama.' Sudah Lebih Dari 3 Kali 
        Alpa');
        return redirect()->route('absen.index')
```

Look on **$nama = Siswa::where('id', '=', $request->siswa_id)->get();**
im trying to get data with **$request->id** and get the **nama** field and then pass to **Session::flash('warning', $nama->nama.' Sudah Lebih Dari 3 
            Kali Alpa');
            return redirect()->route('absen.index');**

> Absen@siswa

```
public function siswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Siswa');
}
```

> Siswa@absen

```
public function absen()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Absen');
}
```

maybe you can help me, Thanks

> Absen Table
>   [image: Absen Table]

[image: Siswa Table]

> Siswa Table

Answer (score 0):

`find($request->id)` i assume that `$request->siswa_id` because i can't find $request->id anywhere in your code

try this using Constraining Eager Loads

```
 $nama = Absen::with(['siswa' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('id', $request->siswa_id);
 }])->get();

 Session::flash('warning', $nama->siswa->nama.' Sudah Lebih Dari 3 
    Kali Alpa');
```

EDIT ANSWERS

Based on table you shown in your question, it can be done like this

```
$namas = Absen::where('siswa',$request->siswa_id)->get(); //will return array because of absent as many siswa

foreach($namas as $nama) {
   $siswa_name = $nama->siswa->nama;
}
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$siswa i got error

Comment: you can't do like this $nama->siswa <-- its a array object..which have many siswa in it..

Answer (score 0):

You can load `Absen` with `siswa`, in where clause while filtering `siswa_id`, it binds to `$request->siswa_id`

```
$nama = Absen::with(['siswa' => function ($query) use($request) {
     $query->where('siswa_id', $request->siswa_id;);
}])->get();
```

Also, you can lazy-eager load:

```
$name = Absen::find($request->id);
```

and then call `load` function to load related model.

```
$name->load('siswa');
```

Since siswa is an array. You can loop through that and find the desired object name. Or you can simply just take the first element by using `first()` function. e.g.

```
 $nama->siswa->first()->anyproperty;
```